# PIL install error: SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install PIL (the Python Imaging Library) using the command:

```
pip install PIL  --allow-unverified PIL --allow-all-external
```

seeing the following errors:

```
gkhan@Gkan ~ $ pip install PIL  --allow-unverified PIL --allow-all-external
Collecting PIL
  PIL is potentially insecure and unverifiable.
  Downloading http://effbot.org/media/downloads/PIL-1.1.7.tar.gz (506kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 507kB 1.5MB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-egu_a9q6/PIL/setup.py", line 182
        print "--- using Tcl/Tk libraries at", TCL_ROOT
                                            ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-egu_a9q6/PIL
```

Comment: Perhaps relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445439/what-does-syntaxerror-missing-parentheses-in-call-to-print-mean-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `python` command on your system runs Python 3, but the setup script for PIL is written for Python 2. Python 2 and Python 3 are two different languages; they look a lot like each other but they aren't compatible, and one of the differences is that `print` requires parentheses in Python 3 but not in Python 2.

Run `pip2` or `pip2.7` instead of `pip3` if these commands are available. Otherwise something like `python2.7 /usr/bin/pip install …` should work.

Note that [so far, it is recommended for `python` to be Python 2](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) but a minority of distributions (Arch Linux at least) install Python 3 as `/usr/bin/python`.